# Visual studio 2017 Evaluate expression (Debug mode)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a place where I can evaluate an expression while debugging.

The only thing I can find is `Execute in interactive` however this doesn't support the direct expression evaluation.

This annoys me since it's one of the features I use the most :)

Does anyone know where it is in `Visual Studio 2017 Community edition`

[image]

Comment: You can always type a command in the box in the upper right corner and Visual Studio will tell you exactly where to find the command. I never noticed a missing command. Usually, when I want to inspect a variable, I use the contextual menu.

Comment: @Phil1970 can you give a screenshot of where that is?

Comment: add the variables to watch window to see the content during debug

Comment: @MarcRasmussen On the caption bar near the close button.

Comment: @Marc Rasmussen, As far as I know, we could  evaluate an expression in some debugging windows like the Watch or QuickWatch or Immediate Window: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee(v=vs.110).aspx, is it what you want to get or you just get the "unable to evaluate expression" error during you watch certain variable? Of course, there are some limitations for Expressions in the debugger for different languages: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za56x861.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have had the same issue. Please see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484632/7932900

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the QuickWatch window (`Debug -> QuickWatch` or `Shift + F9`) you can evaluate expressions while debugging.
[image]
Is this the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: It said "Function XXX has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations".

Comment: @zwcloud Same here. Typing the expression out, re-compiling, and setting a breakpoint on the expression to evaluate the output was faster than disabling the compiler optimizations. FYI in case anyone else thinks about doing the latter.

Comment: I saw the same as @zwcloud and in my case it was because I built a DLL in Release mode, by building with Debug mode it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I think the thing you're looking for is the Immediate window.

```
Debug > Windows > Immediate
```